# Why is {!! Html::linkRoute....!!} being selective? (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I seem to have some inconsistent behaviour here... I'm working through some tutorials, dealing with displaying a user profile and then editing and updating the profile, using form model binding.

The problem is that the Html helper doesn't seem to generate the correct links behind the buttons. When I hover over the buttons, I get something different:

For example, on my edit blade, the SAVE button is supposed to lead to the update route. Hovering over the button shows it to be `http://localhost/dev.rentid.co.nz/public/user/2` when I was expecting it to be `http://localhost/dev.rentid.co.nz/public/user/2/update`

Does `Html::linkRoute` need some additional parameters?

**My show blade**

```
  {!! Html::linkRoute('user.edit', 'Edit', array($thisUser->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block')) !!}
  {!! Html::linkRoute('user.destroy', 'Delete', array($thisUser->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')) !!}
```

**My edit blade:**

```
{!! Form::model($thisUser, ['route' => ['user.update', $thisUser->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
...
{!! Html::linkRoute('user.show', 'Cancel', array($thisUser->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')) !!}
{!! Html::linkRoute('user.update', 'Save', array($thisUser->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block')) !!}
...
{{  Form::close() }}
```

**My routes.php**

```
...
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
....
```

**which produces this:**

```
 GET|HEAD  | user                    | user.index   | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@index
 POST      | user                    | user.store   | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@store
 GET|HEAD  | user/create             | user.create  | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@create
 DELETE    | user/{user}             | user.destroy | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy
 PUT|PATCH | user/{user}             | user.update  | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@update
 GET|HEAD  | user/{user}             | user.show    | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@show
 GET|HEAD  | user/{user}/edit        | user.edit    | rentid\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource routing uses REST, this means that the controller will handle the requested URL based on the type of the request.

Like you've displayed in your routes listing, the route *user/{user}* with a *DELETE* request will be handled by the destroy method, the route *user/{user}* with a *PUT* or *PATCH* request will be handled by the update method, so your URL `http://localhost/dev.rentid.co.nz/public/user/2` is correct. Your update form is ok, but for the delete you have to also use a form to make the request.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['user.destroy', $thisUser->id]]) !!}
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: hi dude, why you use 'method' => 'DELETE' since as far as I know PUT and Delete were removed from html form. I thought we need to use Post and spoof it with hidden method?

Comment: @Mirasan, that is exactly what is happening. Browsers don't support delete and put as far as I know. When you use the LaravelCollective HTML/Forms package, like in this case, the Form facade will automatically add the hidden input with the correct request method.